# How to run a simple Spotify app

Tags: spotify

I want to develop an app with the Spotify API. I have downloaded the Spotify library for Windows and also set path in environmental variables for `spotify.dll`. I am trying to run the simple "hello word" example available on the Spotify developers site but I am getting an error with the Spotify function

> getSpotifyApi(1);

I don't know what exactly this function does.

Is it required to put `API_key` in code file? I don't have the `appkey.c` file in Spotify library right now. Are `API_key` and the `appkey.c` file required for running simple applications? Are there additional requirements for running simple examples?

Comment: You need the application key included in your project and the DLL referenced, besides that there should be no special requirements. What is the error you're getting?

Comment: I am getting "Object expected" error at function call ' sp = getSpotifyApi(1); '

Comment: Is there any public API_key available for running simple applications

Comment: You'd have to be a premium subscriber and apply for an API key at https://developer.spotify.com/en/libspotify/application-key/ and there are samples for Windows in the library download that you could take a look at (none of which use a getSpotifyApi call that I can see)

Comment: What kind of app are you trying to build? Do you want an app INSIDE Spotify as shown here: http://developer.spotify.com/en/spotify-apps-api/overview/ ? If so, then you will need to apply for a developer account. There is no need for the Windows library or any DLL. You will only need that if you are trying to build an 3rd party app which is using the libspotify lib to use it as a streaming service.

Comment: Yes slurmomatic, I want to build third party app. Can you tell how to use libspotify lib as streaming service. I had already submitted my email Id for spottily app developer account. I got email in response clearly telling that “Your Spotify Developer account has been enabled”. Still I am not able to get log into my developer account. In response email they have not mentioned any credentials for log in. I have also tried forgot password option but I got message that is “The email ID you provided is not associated with an active Spotify account”. Is developer account needs premium subscription.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code and your question is confused between the Apps API and LibSpotify.

If you want to make applications INSIDE Spotify, go here for examples and resources: http://developer.spotify.com/en/spotify-apps-api/overview/

If you want to make your own applications that contain Spotify functionality, go here: http://developer.spotify.com/en/libspotify/overview/